# How to redirect url in Django Template View?

Tags: django

I want to send Json data and then redirect back to home.Should i use success_url?

```
   class ApiLoginView(TemplateView):
        template_name = 'index.html'

        def post(self,request):
            email = request.POST.get('login-email')
            password = request.POST.get('login-password')

            API_KEY = GetAPIkey().api_key_token()
            API_URL = GetAPIurl().api_url_token()
            parameter = {
                'authToken':API_KEY,
                'email':email,
                'password':password,
            }
            r = requests.post(url = API_URL, params=parameter)
            if email:
                request.session['email'] = email
            return HttpResponse(r)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`HttpResponseRedirect`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) class as

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect


class ApiLoginView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def post(self, request):
        # Your code
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
```

**UPDATE**
I think you can't redirect to specific page with data by using `HttpResponseRedirect`. So use `render()` function and pass it as `context` data

```
from django.shortcuts import render


class ApiLoginView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def post(self, request):
        # Your code
        return render(request, 'home_template.html', context={'response': r})
```

Comment: oh thanks for answering, so can i go back to 'home' after rendering my response?

Comment: oops... That's a ***flaw*** according to your requirement. I think you need [django messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/)

Comment: oh, so we have both 'template_name' and another template called home in render page.. so its rendering response to the index.html or home_template.html?or home_template here redirects?

Comment: If you want to return json response  instead of HttpResponse use JsonResponse. From the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objectsook

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis he needs to show JSONresponse and redirect to particular page

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak Is the `index.html`  is your home page?

Comment: @JPG yes its my home page with out login. where i do have login pop up modal, so i want to send data and at the same time redirect it to logged in home page

Comment: Now things are more clear. AFAIK, you can't do redirecting and showing messages response on *home page*

Comment: @JPG i dont need to show msg for anything, i am sending a json data to template and after that want to redirect! sorry for not explaining properly..

Comment: then `HttpResponseRedirect` is enough for you. right?

Comment: @JPG oh,then how would i send my context 'r' to the template?im getting confused

Comment: @JPG thank you btw,i will redirect with ajax on success call and send Httpresponse from djago class method...