# How to make sure that when I click the button in django form it redirects me to another page

Tags: django, django-forms

I am making a forms page and I would like when I click the "Submit" button it renders the person on another page that I will create.

**Prenotazioni.html**

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <br><br><br>
  <div class="container" style="max-width: 600px;">
    <form method='POST'> {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <input type='submit' class="btn btn-warning" value='Submit'/>
    </form>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
{% endblock %}
```

**forms.py**

```py
from django import forms
from .models import Prenotazioni

class PrenotazioniForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Prenotazioni
        fields = [
            'Nome',
            'Codice_di_Sicurezza',
            'Telegram',
            'Livello_di_conoscenza_della_economia_da_1_a_10',
        ]
```

The more I search online, the more confused I get. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: In your views function after validating the form being submitted you can just redirect to a new view.

Comment: How can I do?__

Comment: Here is a link see if it helps you; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52324876/how-to-redirect-url-in-django-template-view.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't let me do it.